# Process is terminating due to StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, .net

При попытке сравнения структур , получаю следующее сообщение "Process is terminating due to StackOverflowException."

```
 namespace peregruzka
{
       public struct Name
        {
         public string name;
         public string surname;
         public int age;

    /*     public override bool Equals (object struct_object)
         {
            if (struct_object is Name)
             {
                 Name _name = (Name) struct_object;
                 return name == _name.name && surname == _name.surname && age == _name.age;
             }
             else return false;
         }
         public override int GetHashCode() 
         {
             return name.GetHashCode() ^ surname.GetHashCode() ^ age.GetHashCode();
         } */
        public Name( string n,string s,int a)
        {
            this.name = n;
            this.surname= s;
            this.age = a;

        }

        public static bool operator ==( Name human1, Name human2)
            {
                 if (human1 == human2) return true;
                else return false;

            } 
        public static bool operator !=( Name human1, Name human2)
            {
                if (human1 != human2) return true;
                else return false;

            }

        }
    public class peregruzka
    { 
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Name [] human = 
            {
                 new Name (" tom", "radl", 12 ), 
                 new Name (" dan", "poter", 12 ), 
                 new Name (" fedya", "poter", 123 ), 
                 new Name (" vasia", "loh", 11 ), 
                 new Name (" sada", "maza", 14 ),
                 new Name (" tom","radl",12)
            };

   //     bool equals = (count == count1);
        int arr_legth = human.GetUpperBound(0);
   Console.WriteLine(arr_legth);
        for (int i = 0; i <= arr_legth; i++)
        { 
        count = human[i];
        bool equals;
            for (int j = 0; j <= arr_legth; j++)
            {
                if (j == i) continue;
                if (count == human[j]) Console.WriteLine($"{count} is equal {human[j]}");
            }
        } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: У вас в переопределении операторов `==` и `!=` вызываются эти же операторы, отсюда рекурсия и переполнение стека. В этих методах вы должны описывать свою логику сравнения, то есть сравнивать каждое поле одного с соответствующим полем второго.

Comment: ок, а в чем тогда смысл, если можно и не перегружать операторы, а просто сравнивать поля ?

Comment: Если ты будешь производить такое сравнение только один раз, то смысла нет. А если у тебя сравнение будет более одного раза повторяться, то, наверное, имеет смысл повторяемый код куда-нибудь вынести? Вообще стандартная реализация Equal у структур уже умеет сравнивать по полям, так что можешь её использовать и написать `public static bool operator ==(Name left, Name right) => left.Equals(right);`. "Почему не сделать реализацию по умолчанию для операторов?" Честно говоря - сразу не скажу, не изучал вопрос, похоже исторически сложилось так с языком.

Comment: Спасибо, подумаю над этим , вопрос производительности пока не стоит , поэтому стоит подумать на алгоритмом сравнения , чтоб не подтягивать лишние методы и переопределения!

Comment: Ну, стандартный метод сравнения для структур достаточно быстрый. Особенно, если ты сравниваешь структуры одного типа, тогда производится сравнение даже не по полям, а побайтово. Так что если тебе нужно сравнение только этого типа, то можешь спокойно использовать Equal, побайтово - это самый быстрый метод, который только может быть. Переопределять Equal имеет смысл только, если тебе нужна другая логика сравнения. И опять же, это только для структур. У классов придётся однозначно переопределять метод сравнения.